# What's the meaning of this C++ runtime warning

Tags: c++, templates, linker-errors

I'm getting the following runtime errors when executing my c++ application. Right after the error warnings my app terminates.

```
warning: can't find linker symbol for virtual table for `world2d::SeeIntensityAlgorithm' value
warning:   found `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage' instead
warning: RTTI symbol not found for class 'CppUnit::SourceLine'
```

Any ideas on what the problem is?

Sorry I can't give you any source, the project is big and if I knew where the problem was I would have it much easier fixing the problem myself.

My compiler is gcc.

Comment: is a static class involved? a quick google search shows that the singleton pattern can give that error. Also, having two static classes that depend on each other can cause the error as well.

Comment: Ok thanks so I know where to start searching for the error. Could you write the link to the google search?

Comment: That looks suspiciously like a linker error.  Are you *sure* that's a runtime error?

Comment: do your RTTI build settings match for all targets involved? i am asking because it looks like (a part of) the program expects it to exist, but the type in question may not have been compiled with RTTI enabled. otherwise, a partially con/de-structed object (as JeffC noted) or invalid address/object may be involved.

Comment: This is not a 'runtime warning'. It is a linker *error.*

Answer (score -1):

Are you calling a pure virtual from a constructor? Maybe even indirectly?
See: [Never Call Virtual Functions during Construction or Destruction](https://embeddedartistry.com/blog/2017/03/13/never-call-virtual-functions-during-construction-or-destruction/)